# TableViewCell push to another ViewController very laggy

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I embedded the navigation controller to the UITableViewController, and for every cell I need click the cell to push to another viewcontroller. The problem is when I enable the animation, it would be very laggy clicking the cell. I don't know why.

The code is following as:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SliderViewController *vc = [[SliderViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
}
```

I think it is quite normal so I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: What is inside viewDidLoad of SliderViewController?

Comment: Hi There... I just faced this exact problem. The problem may not be here. IT could be in your viewDidLoad. In my case, it was the piece of code I was using to check if network exist both in this view and the next view.

If you are using something similar, try removing the network checking code and test. If true, figure out a different code to check for network.

Comment: @CRDave it's just an empty view controller and I am trying to customize later.